# Prevent temporary object files hitting disk in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Say I have a CPP file called `test.cpp`. On Ubuntu using gcc 9.3.0 I can use these commands:

- gcc -c test.cpp (creates object file `test.o)`
- gcc test.o -o test.out (creates executable `test.out` from object file `test.o`)
- gcc test.cpp -o test.out (creates only the final executable `test.out`)

The last option is great since no intermediate object files remain after compilation. (I'm unsure whether gcc is doing everything in-memory, or whether object files are temporarily hitting disk before being cleaned up during linking).

On Windows, `cl test.cpp /link /out:test.exe` creates the executable `test.exe`, but also the object file `test.obj`.

Is there a way to prevent MSVC from creating the intermediate object files? Alternatively, is there a link option to ask MSVC to clean up?

Comment: I just use `del %name%.obj >nul 2>&1` command in my custom build `.cmd` script (I don't use VS). It works, but kind of sucks. After all, this wastes my SSD write cycles to write the useless `.obj` files. Its ridiculous that `msvc` have no option to just use the freaking RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The best you can do is use the [`/Fo` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fo-object-file-name?view=vs-2019) to dump the `.obj` file under `%TMPDIR%` or so.

Don't do this for large builds, as `foo/Bar.cpp` and `qux/Bar.cpp` will map to `Bar.obj` and give you very interesting compilation/linking errors.

Comment: Just don't place your `.cpp` files in different folders and never name them the same name.